# Apache subdomain from only one domain

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a problem configuring my apache2 server
what i have:
all domains bla.org .net .com are routed to the server
what i want is:
all this access should be routed to one directory
EXCEPT dev.bla.org
this one should be routed to another directory, but only for .org tld

my configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/dir1
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.bla.org
    ServerAlias dev
    DocumentRoot /var/dir2
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't do what I want. It also routes dev.bla.com etc to `dir2`.
How can i restrict it to .org?
`<VirtualHost *.org:80>` Doesn't work either.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@bla.net
    ServerAlias bla.net *.bla.net bla.org
    DocumentRoot /var/dir1
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.bla.org
    ServerAlias dev.bla.org
    DocumentRoot /var/dir2
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```